# Neo4j: Network trace (path ends at a specific label)

Tags: neo4j

I've modelled a water network using Neo4j. Pipes are nodes with the label "pipe". Valves and other components sitting between pipes are nodes with the label "node". I've added a second label (:dm) to :nodes which separate operational network areas. Finally I've attached interruption nodes to specific pipes, marking places where water supply was affected, say by a burst. The domain looks like this:

```
    (:interruption)-[:ON]->(:pipe)
    (:pipe)-[:LINKED]->(:pipe)
    (:pipe)-[:LINKED]->(:node)
    (:node)-[:LINKED]->(:pipe)
```

I'm trying to return the network starting from an interruption and spreading in all directions but not going through a dm node. This essentially mimics the sort of trace we would do with our GIS. Using the queries below as an example, sometimes I get all possible directions, when in other cases, say where I vary the amount of links, I only get one/some directions.

How can I write the query to consistently return all directions?

Sample 1: Branches extend in two directions, goes through one dm node

```
    // Linked up to 100
    MATCH (i:interruption {ID:40})-[r1:ON]->(p:pipe)
    MATCH (p)-[r2:LINKED]-(p2)
    MATCH (p2)-[r3:LINKED*0..100]-(:dm)
    return r1, r2, r3 limit 200
```

Sample 2:
Branches extend in one direction only

```
    // Linked up to 200
    MATCH (i:interruption {ID:40})-[r1:ON]->(p:pipe)
    MATCH (p)-[r2:LINKED]-(p2)
    MATCH (p2)-[r3:LINKED*0..200]-(:dm)
    return r1, r2, r3 limit 200
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your last `MATCH` clause requires all found paths to end on a `dm` node.

In your first query, if a particular path requires more than 100 steps before encountering a `dm` node, then your query will not match it. You second query goes for 200 steps before it gives up looking for a `dm`, so it will find more paths. (You also have a second problem: your query can match paths with more than one `dm`, which is probably not what you wanted.)

### No `dm` node in `r2` (except first node)

The following query might be appropriate for your needs:

```
MATCH (i:interruption { ID:40 })-[:ON]->(p:pipe)-[r2:LINKED*..100]-(m)
WHERE ALL (r IN r2 
           WHERE NOT "dm" IN LABELS(ENDNODE(r)))
RETURN i, r2
LIMIT 200;
```

It uses a single `MATCH` clause, and requires that none of the nodes in `r2` (starting at its second node) have the `dm` label. (This query also eliminates paths containing multiple `dm` nodes).

### `dm` node only allowed as (first and) last node in `r2`

This alternate query only allows the (first and) last node in `r2` to be a `dm`:

```
MATCH (i:interruption { ID:40 })-[:ON]->(p:pipe)-[r2:LINKED*..100]-(m)
WHERE ALL (i IN RANGE(1, SIZE(r2)-2) 
           WHERE NOT "dm" IN LABELS(ENDNODE(r2[i])))
RETURN i, r2
LIMIT 200;
```